# Find the particular solution for the forced, second order differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose you are given:

$x'' = \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
-50&10 \\
30&-30 \\ \end{array} \right)\ x + \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
5 \\
0 \\ \end{array} \right)\ \sin10t$

Find the particular solution of the system.

A separate part of the problem asked to find the natural frequencies of the masses, which I found to be $\omega_1^2 = 20$ and $\omega_2^2 = 60$.  I tried solving the problem using $(A+\omega^2I)c = -F_0$ such as:

$\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
\omega^2-50&10 \\
30&\omega^2-30 \\ \end{array} \right)\ \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
c_1 \\
c_2 \\ \end{array} \right)\  = \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
-5 \\
0 \\ \end{array} \right)\ $

But I don't know how to continue.  I thought I should plug in $\omega^2 = 20$ (since the force is acting on the first mass), but that results in the system:

$\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
-30&10 \\
30&-10 \\ \end{array} \right)\ \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
c_1 \\
c_2 \\ \end{array} \right)\  = \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
-5 \\
0 \\ \end{array} \right)\ $

Which doesn't have any solutions for $c_1$ and $c_2$ in which I would then be able to write the particular solution as $x(t) = c_1\sin20t + c_2\sin20t$, correct?

Any help would be great.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Look for a particular solution of the form $\pmatrix{a\cr b\cr} \cos(10 t) + \pmatrix{c\cr d\cr} \sin(10 t)$.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know how this helps.

Comment: Plug that in to the differential equation.   You get two equations (one for each component) involving $\cos(10  t)$ and $\sin(10 t)$.  For these to be true for all $t$, the coefficients of $\cos(10 t)$ one the left and right must be equal, and similarly for $\sin(10 t)$.  So you should get four equations in the four unknowns $a,b,c,d$, which you can then solve.

Comment: It's actually a bit easier if you can use complex numbers: find a solution of the form $u e^{10it}$ of the system with $\sin(10t)$ replaced by $e^{10it}$, and take the imaginary part.

Comment: $a,b = 0$ and $c = \frac{-7}{64}$ and $d = \frac{3}{64}$.  Does this seem correct?